# Export Data from Branch

Tags: branch.io

I need to download data form a particular data source with required rows only.
But when I run this script it gives me entire data source with entire columns in response.

```js
{
  "branch_key": "MY_BRANCH_KEY",
  "branch_secret": "MY_BRANCH_SECRET_KEY",
  "export_date": "2018-12-02",
  "custom_data": "eo_custom_event",
  "dimensions": [
    "last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_feature",
    "last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_channel",
    "last_attributed_touch_data_tilde_campaign",
    "last_attributed_touch_data_plus_current_feature"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Data Export API does not have an option to retrieve data based on dimensions and filters. You can check out our [Query API](https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/query-api/#query-api) which will let you add dimensions, filters, data sources, and aggregation rules. We also have a [Query Recipe Book](https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/query-recipe-book/#search) to help you build queries.